# Which class they are telling about in the returned value of PDO::errorCode (void) in php?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

As we know that **PDO::errorCode ( void )** method returns the SQLSTATE where the returned value is the alphanumeric identifier of 5 characters, where the first two characters are the value of **Class** and the rest of the three characters are the value of the **SubClass**. My question is that about which **Class** & **SubClass** they are telling ? Either it is PDO class or anything else ?

Reference Link: [PDO->errorCode(void)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php)

Please can any one tell ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Did you look at the examples?

Comment: Yea there is only one example and it shows that they are pointing about the PDO class, i guess !!

Comment: Then let me confuse you more: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php

Comment: Tip: that method exists for both. What it returns is based off which class you have used it with.

Comment: So it means they are pointing to the PDO calss where the PDO is base class and the PDOStatement is the subclass, may be i am right !!!

Comment: @incredibleHat - Basically they are pointing to the **PDO** class and the concept of subclass means the **PDOStatement** class

Comment: OOps but what about **Class 'IM'**.Please read the documentation in the reference link. Its too confusing !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class and subclass has nothing to do with PDO or PHP classes, or object orientation at all. It just refers to the way that errors are categorized in SQL. As it says in the documentation, the error code is

> a five characters alphanumeric identifier defined in the ANSI SQL-92 standard. Briefly, an SQLSTATE consists of a two characters class value followed by a three characters subclass value.
> ...
>  A class value of `01` indicates a warning
> ...
> Class values other than `01`, except for the class `IM`, indicate an error. The class `IM` is specific to warnings and errors that derive from the implementation of PDO

So except for class `IM`, these codes come from the database. They're the same codes you'll see if you query the database using command line tools and get an error, e.g.

```
mysql> select a from foo bar baz;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'baz' at line 1
```

`42000` is the error code, its class is `42` and subclass is `000`. If you made this same query using PDO, `$pdo->errorCode()` would return `"42000"`, and `$pdo->errorInfo` would return an array like:

```
[ "42000", 
  1004, 
  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'baz' at line 1"   
]
```